# removeFromSuperview() view Not removed from first time

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Ok I have this case where I insert 5 Views programmatically using this method:

```
let starView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.width))

// Set Image & Alpha
starView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "star")
starView.alpha = 1
starView.tag = starIndex

// Add to Super View
self.mainView.addSubview(starView)
```

Please note that starIndex for the 5 views are 1,2,3,4,5 consequently

It's Straightforward.

After a while when an event happens, I use another method to remove these views using this method:

```
func removeOldStars() {  
  for index in 1...5 {
    if let foundView = view.viewWithTag(index) {
      foundView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
}
```

What happens here as a result is that the last element only "number 5" is removed. I have tried several trial and error and found this weird behavior. When I remove the view **twice** using the tag number it works. So for example, if I want to remove view with tag number 3 if I write

```
view.viewWithTag(3).removeFromSuperView()
view.viewWithTag(3).removeFromSuperView()
```

It works!!! if just one time it doesn't do anything. I thought maybe the view is added twice and so it need to be removed twice to notice it, but i Debugged it and no the view is added single time.

I removed the view in the main thread to be sure that its not threading issue not no its not the problem.

I would appreciate your help because this is so weird i really need to understand whats happening here.

Comment: Try not to use tags. It seems likely that you have some other view that has the same tag values; log what `viewWithTag` is returning. I would suggest you simply put your 5 stars into an array and then you don't need to use tags

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 It Worked !! Although I am sure that I never used these tags before!! However Ill try to minimize using them in future

Comment: I would go one step further than @Paulw11 and say never use them. The encourage holding data in the UI which is the exact opposite of what the UI should be doing. As you have seen from the answer there ar always better ways around the problem than using tags.

Comment: Proven :) Thank you @Fogmeister

Comment: Yeah, I would agree actually. My first comment was "tags suck" but I made it more professional :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags, in general, are a brittle way to reference views. As @Paulw11 mentioned, this is very likely an issue with other subviews having identical tag values. 
In this case, I would hold on to instances of the UIImageViews, and then in the `removeOldStars` method, iterate through and call `removeFromSuperview` on the instance directly.

```
//instantiate empty array of UIImageView
var starViews = [UIImageView]()

//assuming your add method name..
func addStar() {

  //your code above up to...

  self.mainView.addSubview(starView)
  starViews.append(starView)      
}

func removeOldStars() {  
    for view in starViews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        //maybe explicitly de allocate the view depending
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @syllabix It Worked !! Although I am sure that I never used these tags before!! However, I'll try to minimize using them in future